# mvn apt:process do not create Q-classes

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, maven

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться, в чем проблема.
Полагаю, я сделал все, но mvn apt:process не генерирует Q-classes.
Может быть, я сделал что-то не так в коде. Или я не написал что-то.
Я делаю новый проект, используя старый код.
И я даже не могу проверить работоспособность до решения этой проблемы.
Я добавил нужный плагин в файле pom.xml.
Вот ссылка на мой проект на GitHub.
https://github.com/zaharovmykola/uniwersytet
Заранее спасибо.

У меня нет ошибок.
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS - но нет созданных классов

Я использую следующие зависимости:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

И следующий плагин:

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Извините, пожалуйста на русском.

Comment: Между прочим я пробую использовать другой подход PagingAndSortingRepository здесь github.com/zaharovmykola/uniwersytet-second-approach